# Как удалить определенный текст из блока с помощью jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, javascript

Мне движок выдает код:

```
<div class="tags"><a href="#">Pretty</a>, <a href="#">Good</a>, <a href="#">Creative</a></div>
```

Запятая мне не нужна. Как можно от нее избавиться с помощью jQuery?

Да, можно было бы и в двжике покопаться, но работа для паблика...

Comment: А при чем тут jQuery? В вашем случае, надо искать закономерности и использовать регулярку. Хотя, я бы смотрел в сторону того, как избежать этого уже при формировании вывода.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот так попробуйте:

```
var text = $('.tags').html();
text = text.replace(',','');
$('.tags').html(text);
```

Comment: @anna241188, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: @Iranda, спасибо

Answer (score 3):

Не до конца понятно, какую запятую тебе нужно убрать. Но в jQuery заменить определенный блок можно так:

```
jQuery('селектор*').html('текст которым ты хочешь заменить');
```

- Про [селекторы](http://anton.shevchuk.name/javascript/jquery-for-beginners-selectors/).

Comment: Так эта штука полностью заменяет текст в блоке. Если посмотреть на пример, то можно видеть запятые после ссылок. Они не нужны

Comment: ну значит тебе нужно сначала вытянуть данные в переменную, потом заменить в ней всё что нужно и засетить в этот блок. Выглядит это примерно так: 

var myDiv = jQuery('селектор').html();

myDiv = тут меняешь всё что нужно;

jQuery('селектор').html(myDiv);

Comment: Так понятно, как это будет)) Вопрос то и стоит в том, как это сделать?

Answer (score 2):

Подключать jQuery ради двух строк JavaScript?

```
var html = document.getElementsByClassName('tags')[0];
html.innerHTML = str.innerHTML.replace(/,/gi, '');
```

Comment: В том то и дело, что jQuery там используется, и вовсе не ради двух.

Comment: Можете считать, что я написал это "на jQuery".